# Getting TypeError when trying to retrieve values from keys in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries in a pandas DataFrame:

```
 0      [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]                                                                                                     
 1      [{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 88, 'name': 'Fantasy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]                                                                                                    
 2      [{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 77, 'name': 'Horror'}]
```

I am trying to get all the names from a single row into a simple list of Strings, like: "Horror, family, drama" etc for each row in the dataset.

I tried this code but I am getting the error: string indices must be integers

```
for y in df:
    names = [x['name'] for x in y]
```

Any help is appriciated

Comment: Iterating over a data-frame iterates over the names of it's columns...

Comment: In this case my df is only consisting of one column. Even though if i skip the first loop I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this is dict not a list. you should using `.get`

```
[[y.get('name') for y in x ]for x in df['your columns']]
Out[578]: 
[['Animation', 'Comedy', 'Family'],
 ['Adventure', 'Fantasy', 'Family'],
 ['Romance', 'Horror']]
```

Convert str

```
import ast
df.a=df.a.apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
Dunno why it worked for you?

Comment: @JokkeMedKniven `import ast;df.a=df.a.apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: **Iterating over a data-frame iterates over the names of its columns**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i am not sure it is data frame  or a Series... since the data show just like Series

Comment: I extracted only the columns I needed from the DataFrame so I think that makes it a Series?

Comment: @JokkeMedKniven you need to provide a [mcve]. How did you even end up with such a data-frame? It should probably just be a list or maybe a `dict`. Or better yet, you should be using this directly on the `pd.DataFrame` constructor to get a df of `id` and `name` columns

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a data-frame iterates over the *names* of the columns, `:

```
In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

In [17]: for x in df:
    ...:     print(x)
    ...:
a
b
```

It is like a `dict` that would iterate over it's keys.

You need something like:

```
df['your_column'].apply(lambda x: [d['name'] for d in x])
```